# Determine max slope of slowly descending signal

Tags: algorithm

I have an analog power signal from a motor.  The signal ramps up quickly, but powers off slowly over the course of several seconds.  The signal looks almost like a series of plateaus on the descent.  The problem is that the signal doesn't settle back to zero. It settles back to an intermediate level unknown, and varying from motor to motor.  See chart below.
I'm trying to find a way determine when the motor is off and at that intermediate level.
My thought is to find and store the max point, and calculate the slopes thereafter until the max slope is greater than some large negative slope value like -160 (~ -60 degrees), and declare that the motor must be powering off.  The sample points below are with all duplicates removed. (there's about 5000 samples typically).
My problem is determining the X values.  In the formula (y2-y1) / (x2 - x1), the x values could far enough away in time that the slope never appears greater than -30 degrees.  Picking an absolute number like 10 would fix this, but is there a more mathematically correct method?

The data shows me calculating slope with method described above and the max of 921. ie (y2 -y1) / ( (10+1) - 10).  In this scheme, at datapoint 9, i would say the motor is "Off".  I'm looking for a more precise means to determine an X value rather than randomly picking 10 for instance.

`+---+-----+----------+
| X |  Y  |  Slope   |
+---+-----+----------+
| 1 |  65 | 856.000  |
| 2 |  58 | 863.000  |
| 3 |  57 | 864.000  |
| 4 | 638 | 283.000  |
| 5 | 921 | 0.000    |
| 6 | 839 | -82.000  |
| 7 | 838 | -83.000  |
| 8 | 811 | -110.000 |
| 9 | 724 | -197.000 |
+---+-----+----------+`

[image]

Comment: When the motor turns off, is there a minimum amount of time before it turns on again?

Comment: Are you free to take as much processor-time as you want to analyze the data, or must you come up with answers in real-time more or less as the data comes in?

Comment: There's no min time before motor restarts.  The graph shows a quick restart just to show the profiles are similar.
The decision should be made in real-time until we establish what that intermediate level is.  Usually during initial config,  after that we'll have that intermediate value stored and be able to compare current power vs off.

Comment: Do you have another source of information that lets you know whether the motor is off, or are you constrained to inferring it from the voltages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: A much simpler answer:**

Since your motor is either ON or OFF, and ON wattages are strictly higher than OFF wattages, you should be able to discriminate between ON and OFF wattages by maintaining an average wattage, reporting ON if the current measurement is higher than the average and OFF if it is lower.

```
Count = 0
Average = 500
```

Whenever a measurement comes in,

```
Count = Count + 1
Average = Average + (Measurement - Average) / Count
Return Measurement > Average ? ON : OFF
```

This represents an average of all the values the wattage has ever been.  If we want to eventually "forget" the earliest values (before the motor was ever turned on), we could either keep a buffer of recent values and use that for a moving average, or approximate a moving average with an IIR like

```
Average = (1-X) * Average + X * Measurement
```

for some X between 0 and 1 (closer to 0 to change more slowly).

---

**Original answer:**

You could treat this as an online clustering problem, where you expect three clusters (before the motor turns on, when the motor is on, and when the motor is turned off), or perhaps four (before the motor turns on, peak power, when the motor is running normally, and when the motor turns off).  In effect, you're trying to learn what it looks like when a motor is on (or off).

If you don't have any other information about whether the motor is on or off (which could be used to train a model), here's a simple approach:

```
Define an "Estimate" to contain:
    float Value
    int Count

Define an "Estimator" to contain:
    float TotalError  = 0.0
    Estimate COLD_OFF = {Value = 0,    Count = 1}
    Estimate ON       = {Value = 1000, Count = 1}
    Estimate WARM_OFF = {Value = 500,  Count = 1}

    a function Update_Estimate(float Measurement)
        Find the Estimate E such that E.Value is closest to Measurement
        Update TotalError = TotalError + (E.Value - Measurement)*(E.Value - Measurement)
        Update E.Value = (E.Value * E.Count + P) / (E.Count + 1)
        Update E.Count = E.Count + 1
        return E
```

This takes initial guesses for what the wattages of these stages should be and updates them with the measurements.  However, this has some problems.  What if our initial guesses are off?

You could initialize some number of Estimators with different possible (e.g. random) guesses for COLD_OFF, ON, and WARM_OFF; after receiving a measurement, let each Estimator update itself and aggregate their values somehow.  This aggregation should reward the better estimates.  Since you're storing TotalError for each estimate, you could just pick the output of the Estimator that has the lowest TotalError so far, or you could let the Estimators vote (giving each Estimator's vote a weight proportional to 1/(TotalError + 1) or something like that).

Comment: Thanks Jerry.  The "OFF" average is the easiest to get as i just average until i see a large positive slope.  Once that occurs i reset the averaging and call this the "ON" (motorRunning) average.                                     Your "estimator" has merit though, and I may test using this to gauge when the motor is at peak running power, to help improve the estimate, so that anything outside of the std deviation is considered "WARM_OFF".     Here's a cool algorithm i poached for keeping a running average and std dev:  http://www.johndcook.com/blog/standard_deviation/